# How to achieve side action buttons on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to achieve the hover behavior you see in Notion tables. When you hover over the rows, the side action buttons are rendered.

[image]

The part I'm trying to figure out is how they are able to achieve the same effect when you hovering outside of the table, but still within the height of the row.

[image]

The width of the table or the rows don't extend where the buttons show up as shown in the image below

[image]

So my question is how can we design or implement in JavaScript so that if the cursor hovers over the screen and the cursor happens to be within the space of the row (even if it's outside of the table) it should render the action buttons.

Comment: In your code attempt you would want to first solve this problem: How to know which row number the "cursor" is on based on the Y coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with CSS only. Essentially you just need CSS that does the equivalent of this:

```css
.row .side-action-button {
    opacity: 0;
    transition-duration: 200ms;
}
.row:hover .side-action-button {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

as for the "even if it's outside of the table" you should just make the table as big as you want it to be and style it to look smaller if that's what you want. This will be the easiest and most accessible